# Problems with executeQuery

Tags: java, sql, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to use MySQL and jdbc, but I can't use the executeQuery command, do you know why?
It's the first time I've programmed in Java and integrated SQL into the program, I don't know what's wrong.

[image]

```
import java.beans.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //TIP Press <shortcut actionId="ShowIntentionActions"/> with your caret at the highlighted text
        // to see how IntelliJ IDEA suggests fixing it.
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jdbc-book", "root","root");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        //("select * from published_books");
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by fixing imports - `java.beans.Statement` not same as `java.sql.Statement`

Comment: Ohhh perfect, all it took was a change java.beans.Statement with java.sql.Statement. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved! All it took was a change to the `import` statements, replacing `java.beans.Statement` with `java.sql.Statement`. And add a try-catch.

```
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jdbc-book", "root", "root");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from published_books");

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString("title"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "all it took was a change java.beans.Statement with java.sql.Statement" - you forgot that you also needed to add the argument - the query - to `executeQuery()`

Answer (score -1):

First, you have to download mysql-connector-java.jar into the project sturcture in Intellij. and add **Class.forname("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")** into the code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Main{

 public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        //This is the necessary part you have missed
        Class.forname("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jdbc-book","root","root");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from published_books");

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println(resultSet.getString("title"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```